# How to resolve this ambiguous grammar?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I have written this grammar:

```
expr        : multExpr ( ('+' | '-') multExpr )*;
multExpr    : atom ( ('*' | '/') atom )*;
atom    : INT | FLOAT | ID | '(' expr ')';
condition   : cond ('or' cond)*;
cond    : c1 ('and' c1)*;
c1      : ('not')? c2;
c2      : '(' condition ')' | boolean;
boolean : expr (relop expr | ²) | 'true' | 'false';
relop   : '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' | '==' | '!=';
```

I have omitted the lexer rules for INT,FLOAT,ID as it is obvious.

The problem is c2 rule, it is ambiguous because of '(', I could not find the solution, can you offer me a solution?

Comment: What's the super-scripted `2` doing in `boolean`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
expr      : orExpr; 
orExpr    : andExpr ('or' andExpr)*;
andExpr   : relExpr ('and' relExpr)*;
relExpr   : addExpr (relop addExpr)?;
relop     : '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' | '==' | '!=';
addExpr   : multExpr (('+' | '-') multExpr)*;
multExpr  : unaryExpr (('*' | '/') unaryExpr)*;
unaryExpr : 'not'? atom;
atom      : INT | FLOAT | ID | 'true' | 'false' | '(' expr ')';
```

The unary `not` usually has a higher precedence than you're trying to do now.

This will allow for expressions like `42 > true`, but checking such semantics can come when you're walking the AST/tree.

**EDIT**

The input `"not(a+b >= 2 * foo/3.14159) == false"` would now be parsed like this (ignoring spaces):

[image]

And if you set the output to AST and mix in some tree rewrite operators (`^` and `!`):

```
options {
  output=AST;
}

// ...

expr      : orExpr; 
orExpr    : andExpr ('or'^ andExpr)*;
andExpr   : relExpr ('and'^ relExpr)*;
relExpr   : addExpr (relop^ addExpr)?;
relop     : '<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=' | '==' | '!=';
addExpr   : multExpr (('+' | '-')^ multExpr)*;
multExpr  : unaryExpr (('*' | '/')^ unaryExpr)*;
unaryExpr : 'not'^ atom | atom;
atom      : INT | FLOAT | ID | 'true' | 'false' | '('! expr ')'!;
```

you'd get:

[image]

Comment: this works for conditional expressions, but I'm using expr(in your grammar: addExpr) for math stuff, then I should define a separate expr I think for that. and another thing, you have defined unaryExpr but not used it.

Comment: ,thanks your solution is correct i think, but i was thinking, is it wise to use Syntactic Predicates like this:       c2 : ( '(' atom ('*'atom)* (('+'|'-')atom('*'atom)*)* ')') =>  boolean | '(' condition ')'

Comment: @nafiseh, my opinion: if you can, avoid predicates as much as possible. I know, sometimes you need them, but I prefer to construct the AST more loosely and then validate the semantic structure of the AST at a later stage: it keeps the grammar so much friendlier for the eyes! :)

Comment: ok, and last question! what a bout Backtracking? when it is enabled, does the grammar still need to be unambiguous?

Comment: @nafiseh, what do you mean? By using a predicate, the parser will follow (or "look") what you used in that predicate, and when it really "sees" it, it takes that path, and if it does not see what you've put in the predicate, it backtracks from it and takes an alternative path. But perhaps you meant global backtracking (`backtrack=true;` in the `options`)? I really wouldn't do that if you're just trying to fix a single ambiguity! That's like squashing a fly with a large iron frying pan :)

Comment: yes I meant global backtracking. Thank you very much Bart for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You problem stems from the fact that the '(' could be the start of either the first alternative for `c2` or the last alternative for `atom`. Just for example, given input like `((x+y) > (a+b))`, the first open paren is the beginning of a `c2`, but the second is the beginning of an `atom`. [edit: And the parser has no indication of which way to go until some arbitrary point later -- for example, it can't know that the first open paren is the beginning of a `c2` until it encounters the `>`. For example, if that were a `*` instead, then both the opening parens would be beginnings of `atom`s.]

One possible way to handle it would be to unify the rules for arithmetic and Boolean expressions, so you only have one rule with `'(' expression ')`, and the `expression` might be arithmetic or Boolean. This often, however, has the side-effect of producing rather loose typing, with relatively free conversion between arithmetic and Boolean expressions (at least at the parser level -- you can then enforce the types as rigidly as you like in the semantics).

Edit: In Pascal, for example, the rules run something like this (simplifying a tiny bit):

```
expression: simple_expression ( rel_op simple_expression )*

simple_expression: ( '+' | '-')? term ( ('+' | '-' | 'or' ) term )*

term: factor ( ( '/' | '*' | 'div' | 'mod' | 'and') factor )*

factor: constant | variable | function_call | '(' expression ')' | 'not' factor
```

Comment: yes, I think I have to do this, and one question, how do some well-known languages like java, pascal ,.. resolve this? do they act like this in their grammar? or do they use different approaches like Backtracking and somethings like this?

Comment: Depends on the language. Fortran uses loose rules and backtracking. Pascal uses about what I've outlined above -- one set of rules for all expressions, Boolean or otherwise. Most others do about like Pascal. See edited answer -- I've added the rules from Pascal.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you define c1 as the following?

```
('not')? (('(' condition ')') | boolean)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still be ambiguous with the `atom` rule?

Comment: no , the problem still exists, if the boolean goes to expr, expr goes to  multExpr , then atom and then '(' expr ')'.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem is to split it into two sets of lexer rules and apply them sequentially to the input (one for the math stuff, the other for the boolean).

Comment: so you mean I should not go to expr from boolean anymore?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to achieve.  You could separate them and create a booleanexpr instead of reusing expr.  It would be helpful if you could list some sample valid inputs.  Is `true and (4 + 3) /4` a valid expression for example?

Comment: yes, then it would be like what Bart suggested, and I need to define 2 types of expressions. actually I have a grammar for the whole of a language, I have math expressions too.